# MYSql with C# in Visual Studio. How to return a boolean if a database exists

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a WPF MVVM Light application and I'd like to have a Boolean Method that uses a MYSql Query and C# to Progammatically determine if the Database exists.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe something with a query like :

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'Mark'), 'Yes','No')
```

Or:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DBName'
```

I've got methods that will query the database but I'd like to have a checksum that determines if the db exists.  If I use the code below it will error out so I'd like to determine first if the db exists and if it does query it.

```
    static public Project.Project QueryProject(string projDatabaseName)
    {
        Project.Project proj = new Project.Project();
        string connStr = "server=localhost;database=" + projDatabaseName + ";user=******;port=3306;password=********;";
        string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM " + projDatabaseName + ".project";
        MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();

        try
        {
            MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                proj.ProjectID = int.Parse(myReader["ProjectID"].ToString());
                proj.ProjectName = myReader["ProjectName"].ToString();
                proj.ProjectStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["ProjectStartDate"]);
                proj.ProjectEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["ProjectEndDate"]);
                proj.ProjectNotes = myReader["ProjectNotes"].ToString();
            }
            myReader.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        return proj;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried connecting to the server without selecting a database and run query `show databases;`

Comment: How so?  If I do a Myconnection.Open it will error out.

Comment: use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as the database. If the show databases doesn't work try `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`

Comment: Also if you use a using statement for your connection it creates a finally statement and closes the connection for you `using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(connStr)) {`

Comment: Can you post an example with code?

Comment: See my answer. It worked for me. It will only list databases you have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the database the use show databases.

```
public bool DatabaseExists(string dbname)
{
string connStr = "server=localhost;database=INFORMATION_SCHEMA;";

using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
 string sql = "show databases";
 MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
 myConnection.Open();
 MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
 while (myReader.Read())
 {
   string db =  myReader["Database"].ToString();
   if (db == dbname)
     return true;
 }
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: This did it.  I really appreciate it.  Good Stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'databaseName';
```

It returns an empty set if it doesn't exist.

Comment: That's what I'd like to do but I'd like to do it with out throwing an error.

Comment: It's bad practice to use `try catch` as a conditional statement